# github merge extra commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

Maybe this is a bug report about github, but I want to make sure it is not something we do incorrectly...

A pull request on github showed 3 commits. Only the last of these was supposed to be there. The other two have been merged earlier. I was assigned and I did not merge the pull request. (The other two commits changed many files and lines.)

Instead I created a new branch into which I cherry picked the wanted commit and created a new pull request that is sent back.

However, we do not understand why this happened. It is also strange that the original borked pull request showed that only 1 file changed, while opening up the commits several files were listed.

One theory that we entertain is that the submitter merged master into his feature branch before submitting the pull request and that somehow confused github.

Note, that I pulled the branch from the submitter's forked repo and looked at the state. It looked ok, and I do not understand why the older commits from master were listed by the github gui.

Any ideas?